# How to call reduce an array of objects and based on two conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nestjs, reduce

I'm having trouble solving this issue, this is my array of objects

```
gamesAndChoosenNumbers: [
  {
    choosenNum: '15',
    count: 10,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '15',
    count: 5,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '16',
    count: 20,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '16',
    count: 20,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '16',
    count: 10,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '150',
    count: 10,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '150',
    count: 10,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '155',
    count: 20,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
 {
    choosenNum: '155',
    count: 20,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '200',
    count: 10,
    game: 'BOX',
    gameCode: 'box',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '200',
    count: 10,
    game: 'BOX',
    gameCode: 'box',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '155',
    count: 20,
    game: 'BOX',
    gameCode: 'box',
  },
];
```

so I want to reduce this array based on the  **choosenNum** and **game** values and merge them and replace the count value with all of the other same objects **count'**s sum,

the result I'm exoecting to get is this

```
gamesAndChoosenNumbers: [
  {
    choosenNum: '15',
    count: 15,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '16',
    count: 50,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '150',
    count: 20,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '155',
    count: 40,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '200',
    count: 20,
    game: 'BOX',
    gameCode: 'box',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '155',
    count: 20,
    game: 'BOX',
    gameCode: 'box',
  },
];
```

I tried so much but could'nt solve this issue with this code

```
 const duplicateElementa = gamesAndChoosenNumbers.reduce((x, y, i) => {
      console.log({ i, x, y });
      if (x.map((it) => it.choosenNum).includes(y.choosenNum)) {
        console.log({ i1: i, x1: x[i - 1], y1: y });
        if (x[i - 1].game === y.game) {
          return [...x, { ...y, count: x[i - 1]?.count + y.count }];
        }
      } else {
        return [...x, y];
      }
    }, []);

    const nondupes = gamesAndChoosenNumbers.filter(
      (it) => !dupeNums.includes(it.choosenNum),
    );
    const dupesMerged = duplicateElementa.map((it, i, arr) => {
      const gt = arr.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);
      const st = gt.reduce((x, y, i, carr) => {
        if (
          x.map((it) => it.choosenNum).includes(y.choosenNum) &&
          x.map((it) => it.game).includes(y.game)
        ) {
          return x;
        } else {
          return [...x, y];
        }
      }, []);

      return st;
    })[0];

    const final: [] = dupesMerged
      .filter((it) => {
        console.log(nondupes.map((u) => u.choosenNum).includes(it.choosenNum));
        if (!nondupes.map((u) => u.choosenNum).includes(it.choosenNum)) {
          return it;
        }
      })
      .concat(nondupes);
```

here the final variable will have the answer but I got screwed when the 155 repeats in two code blocks!!!. I'm stuck...,,please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made things complicated,below is a simple reference for you using `reduce()`(composite a new key combined by choosenNum and game )

```js
let data = [
  {
    choosenNum: '15',
    count: 10,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '15',
    count: 5,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '16',
    count: 20,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '16',
    count: 20,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '16',
    count: 10,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '150',
    count: 10,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '150',
    count: 10,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '155',
    count: 20,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
 {
    choosenNum: '155',
    count: 20,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '200',
    count: 10,
    game: 'BOX',
    gameCode: 'box',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '200',
    count: 10,
    game: 'BOX',
    gameCode: 'box',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '155',
    count: 20,
    game: 'BOX',
    gameCode: 'box',
  },
]

let result = data.reduce((a,c) =>{
  let key = c.choosenNum+ '_' + c.game
  let obj = a.find(i => i.choosenNum+ '_' + i.game == key )
  if(!obj){
    a.push({...c})
  }else{
    obj.count += c.count
  }
 return a
},[])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
gamesAndChoosenNumbers = [{
    choosenNum: '15',
    count: 10,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '15',
    count: 5,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '16',
    count: 20,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '16',
    count: 20,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '16',
    count: 10,
    game: 'AB',
    gameCode: 'double',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '150',
    count: 10,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '150',
    count: 10,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '155',
    count: 20,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '155',
    count: 20,
    game: 'SUPER',
    gameCode: 'super',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '200',
    count: 10,
    game: 'BOX',
    gameCode: 'box',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '200',
    count: 10,
    game: 'BOX',
    gameCode: 'box',
  },
  {
    choosenNum: '155',
    count: 20,
    game: 'BOX',
    gameCode: 'box',
  },
];
finalArr = gamesAndChoosenNumbers.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const findObj = acc.findIndex(_item => item.choosenNum === _item.choosenNum && item.game === _item.game);
  console.log(findObj)
  if (findObj >= 0) {
    acc[findObj] = {
      ...item,
      count: item.count + findObj.count,
    }
    return acc
  }
  return [...acc, item];
}, [])
console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ... use an object like this?

```js
const gamesAndChoosenNumbers = [
  {choosenNum: '15', count: 10, game: 'AB', gameCode: 'double'},
  {choosenNum: '15', count: 5, game: 'AB', gameCode: 'double'},
  {choosenNum: '16', count: 20, game: 'AB', gameCode: 'double'},
  {choosenNum: '16', count: 20, game: 'AB', gameCode: 'double'},
  {choosenNum: '16', count: 10, game: 'AB', gameCode: 'double'},
  {choosenNum: '150', count: 10, game: 'SUPER', gameCode: 'super'},
  {choosenNum: '150', count: 10, game: 'SUPER', gameCode: 'super'},
  {choosenNum: '155', count: 20, game: 'SUPER', gameCode: 'super'},
  {choosenNum: '155', count: 20, game: 'SUPER', gameCode: 'super'},
  {choosenNum: '200', count: 10, game: 'BOX', gameCode: 'box'},
  {choosenNum: '200', count: 10, game: 'BOX', gameCode: 'box'},
  {choosenNum: '155', count: 20, game: 'BOX', gameCode: 'box'},
];

const results = {}
gamesAndChoosenNumbers.forEach(obj => {
  if(!results[obj.choosenNum + obj.game]) results[obj.choosenNum + obj.game] = obj;
  else results[obj.choosenNum + obj.game].count += obj.count;
});

console.log(Object.values(results));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply `reduce` your array and check whether you have already an item with the `choosenNum` and `game` properties that match the current iteration's item `choosenNum` and `game` properties:

- if yes, then just add the current item's `count` to the item found in the *reduced* array.
- if no, just push the current item to the *reduced* array.

And here's a live demo:

```js
const gamesAndChoosenNumbers = [{
      choosenNum: '15',
      count: 10,
      game: 'AB',
      gameCode: 'double',
    },
    {
      choosenNum: '15',
      count: 5,
      game: 'AB',
      gameCode: 'double',
    },
    {
      choosenNum: '16',
      count: 20,
      game: 'AB',
      gameCode: 'double',
    },
    {
      choosenNum: '16',
      count: 20,
      game: 'AB',
      gameCode: 'double',
    },
    {
      choosenNum: '16',
      count: 10,
      game: 'AB',
      gameCode: 'double',
    },
    {
      choosenNum: '150',
      count: 10,
      game: 'SUPER',
      gameCode: 'super',
    },
    {
      choosenNum: '150',
      count: 10,
      game: 'SUPER',
      gameCode: 'super',
    },
    {
      choosenNum: '155',
      count: 20,
      game: 'SUPER',
      gameCode: 'super',
    },
    {
      choosenNum: '155',
      count: 20,
      game: 'SUPER',
      gameCode: 'super',
    },
    {
      choosenNum: '200',
      count: 10,
      game: 'BOX',
      gameCode: 'box',
    },
    {
      choosenNum: '200',
      count: 10,
      game: 'BOX',
      gameCode: 'box',
    },
    {
      choosenNum: '155',
      count: 20,
      game: 'BOX',
      gameCode: 'box',
    },
  ],
  /**
   * merge the items from "gamesAndChoosenNumbers" based on their "game" and "choosenNum" properties.
   */
  merged = gamesAndChoosenNumbers.reduce((a, c) => {
    // "gameAndNum" tells us whether we have an item with "game" and "choosenNum" properties matching the current iteration's item.
    const gameAndNum = a.find(item => item.game == c.game && item.choosenNum == c.choosenNum);
    // if yes, then we add increment the count property. Else, that means we're dealing with a new (game, choosenNum) pairs so we push the current iteration item to the reduced array.
    gameAndNum ? gameAndNum.count += c.count : a.push(c);
    // return the reduced array 
    return a;
  }, []);

// print the result
console.log(merged);
```